# Passing char-array by value when char expected

Tags: c

```
void func(char a, int num)
{
    printf("%c",a);
}

int main()
{
     func("a", 6); //not func('a',6);
     printf("\n");
     func("b", 2); //not func('b',6);
}
```

I understand I am passing a char array of a and b with a null character `\0`.
Could someone how it ends up printing the characters `$` and `&`?

Comment: It doesn't compile for me. What compiler lets that all through?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could end up printing anything pretty much, probably part of the adresses of `"a"` and `"b"` match the ascii code of `$` and `&`.

Comment: How would that happen consistently? I tested across several computers, why would it print the same set of values everywhere?

Comment: @Cthulhu, Forgive me if this is completely wrong, but from my experiences with Windows, applications usually have a base address of 0x400000, so if that and endianness were kept constant across computers, they could all print the same thing. There's never really any telling with UB, though.

Comment: @chris I didn't know that. Tested on CentOS. Different characters indeed. Thanks! I'll look into the common base-address thing.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing pointer to a literal string but the `func` expects a character. Change it to receive an array:

```
void func(char *a, int num)
{
    printf("%c",a[0]); // also note that to print a char you need to
                       // 'select' a char from the array
}
```

Otherwise you'll end up printing to a char that is the ascii representation of whatever the address of `a` has as the first byte.

Comment: I realize what is happening. My question was regarding why it prints those exact characters.

Comment: they are random characters based on the address of those strings. If you compile this in a different machine (or use different compilation options) you may get some different characters.

Comment: Seems to be the same across all Windows machines, but yes, different ones on other operating systems. @chris has explained in his comment why.